# Keep tag description when editing

Tags: feature-request

It would be good to still be able to check tag's description when editing a question without having to click it.

**How to reproduce:** (needs **2k+** rep)

1. Go to a question;
   1.1 Hover over the tags to display a ballon with a tag description;
2. Click edit (so it edits in the same page);
3. Hover tags now (can't see the description - without clicking it);

**Reason:**

- It's easier to check if there are any unrelated tags. Just hover the tag...
- Misclicks on the `x`;

Comment: How come I'm never able to find those duplicates.. feelsbadman... Thks for finding it @Laurel

Comment: You need to get a black belt in Dupe Fu.